# How to fix error in user verification plugin on new user creation?

Tags: authentication, laravel-5

In my my laravel 5.7.3 application I have wizard for user's creation.
It worked, but I got error when on user creation I attached plugin https://github.com/jrean/laravel-user-verification/

My model app/User.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use DB;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use App\Http\Traits\funcsTrait;
use App\library\ImagePreviewSize;


//class User extends Authenticatable
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    use funcsTrait;
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;
...
```

and in controls app/Http/Controllers/AccountController.php:

```
public function postConfirm() // create new user with all related data
{
    DB::beginTransaction();
    try {
        $newAccountData = Session::get($this->register_session_key);

        $avatar_filename = ! empty($newAccountData['avatar_filename']) ? $newAccountData['avatar_filename'] : '';
        $avatar_filename_path = ! empty($newAccountData['avatar_filename_path']) ? $newAccountData['avatar_filename_path'] : '';

        $newUser             = new User();
        $newUser->username   = $newAccountData['username'];
        $newUser->email      = $newAccountData['email'];
        $newUser->password   = $newAccountData['password'];
        $newUser->first_name = $newAccountData['first_name'];
        $newUser->last_name  = $newAccountData['last_name'];
        $newUser->phone      = $newAccountData['phone'];
        $newUser->website    = $newAccountData['website'];
        $newUser->status     = 'N';
        if ( ! empty($avatar_filename)) {
            $newUser->avatar = $newAccountData['avatar_filename'];
        }
        $newUser->save();


        $ret1= UserVerification::generate($newUser);
```

On the last Line I got error :

```
The model instance provided is not compliant with this package.
```

In the docs linked above I read :
The model instance provided is not compliant with this package. It must implement the authenticatable interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable

I tried to modify my user modfel with lines:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use DB;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use App\Http\Traits\funcsTrait;
use App\library\ImagePreviewSize;


class User extends Authenticatable
{
    ...
```

But I got error:

```
Class App\User cannot extend from interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable
```

Why error and how to fix it ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your `User` Model must extends `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User` with laravel by default alias it as `Authenticatable`

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{

}
```

In your code you extends the `Authenticatable` Contract which is a PHP Interface and not a PHP class

Comment: Please, look at the beginning of my code : I madeso and got error : "The model instance provided is not compliant with this package.   " - I tried to fix it by docs limk.